# How to keep one or more rows of a DataGrid always at the top even after sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a DataGrid (on the View) bound to an ObservableCollection (on the ViewModel).

To this ObservableCollection, I am programmatically adding a "magic row", since the selected item will be used to sort another collection elsewhere, and I add this dummy row to "clear" the filtering.

Currently, when the View loads, my magic string always appears on top (since I insert it at index `0`), but as soon as I click on the header to change sorting order, the rows rearrange alphabetically and my magic row is lost in the rubble.

What I want is that the magic row to always appear on top, even when I click on the header to change the sorting order.

ViewModel:

```
// (...)

public ObservableCollection<FilteringItem> ItemTypes
{
    get
    {
        var result = new ObservableCollection<FilteringItem>(_setups.Select(n => n.ItemType)
                                                             .Distinct()
                                                             .Select(s => new FilteringItem(s, s))
                                                             .OrderBy(v => v.Name));


        // Magic Happens Here: adding a "magic" row to remove filtering
        // (that is, "allow all") when used by some filtering method elsewhere;
        string allString = String.Format("All ({0})", result.Count);
        var filteringAll = new FilteringItem(allString, "");

        result.Insert(0, filteringAll);

        return result;
    }

}
// (...)

public class FilteringItem
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public FilteringItem(string name, string val)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = val;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemTypes}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tipo" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got it to work thanks to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/08/26/improving-microsoft-datagrid-ctp-sorting-performance.aspx).

The "secret" was to intercept the `Sorting` event (setting `e.Handled` to `true`), then casting the DataGrid.ItemsSource to `ListCollectionView`, and then assigning a custom `IComparer` to `ListCollectionView.CustomSort` property.

Then, while sorting, you somehow identify your fixed row (by null value, in my case), and make it always go to the top (which in turn depends on `ListSortDirection`).

```
public partial class ViewContainingDataGrid : UserControl
{
    public ViewContainingDataGrid()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void datagrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        SmartSort(sender, e.Column);
    }

    private void SmartSort(object sender, DataGridColumn column)
    {
        ListSortDirection direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ?
                             ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

        column.SortDirection = direction;
        var dg = sender as DataGrid;
        var lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dg.ItemsSource);
        lcv.CustomSort = new SmartSorter(direction);
    }

}

public class SmartSorter : IComparer
{
    public ListSortDirection Direction { get; private set; }

    public SmartSorter(ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        Direction = direction;
    }


    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        string valorx = x as string;
        string valory = y as string;

        int comparison = valorx.CompareTo(valory);
        if (Direction == ListSortDirection.Descending)
            comparison *= -1;

        // Override the sorting altogether when you find the special row value
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valorx))
            comparison = -1;
        else
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valory))
            comparison = 1;

        return comparison;
    }
}
```